Return value of cell if another cell contains values
Take this table:

I need to look in the column "Name" for Peter, Ann or both and if found, then return the value from the Bonus cell.
I've tried several suggestions from Copilot - for example (translated from Dansih Excel):
=FILTER([Bonus]; (OR([Name]="Ann"; [Name]="Peter")))
=IF(OR([Name]="Ann"; [Name]="Peter"); [Bonus]; "")
=SUMIFS([Bonus], [Name], "Ann") + SUMIFS([Bonus], [Name], "Peter")

and none of them works.
Any suggestion?
UPDATE
Using the formuala:
=SUM(BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann";"Peter"};Table1[Name]));OR)*Table1[Bonus])
...returns 0 (on Danish Pc's we use ";" in formalas).


Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell D3
=IF(OR(1-ISERR(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},[@Name]))),[@Bonus],"")


Or,
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},[@Name]))),[@Bonus],"")


If the names are not case-insensitive, then can use SEARCH() in place of FIND() function as well!

Updated Screenshot:


Working Formula:
=SUM(BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},Table5[Name])),OR)*Table5[Bonus])


Alternatively using MMULT():
=SUM((MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},Table1[Name]))),{1;1})>0)*Table1[Bonus])



Thanks!! It works :) ...  I changed the .... [@Bonus],"") ... to [@Bonus],0) ... and if I in cell like F7 enter this formula .... =SUM(IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"}, Table1[Name]))), Table1[Bonus]; 0)) ,,, then I get a value of 0 - I would expect 90. Any idea why? Thanks again.

@MojoDK will it be 90 or 80? =SUM(BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},Table1[Name])),OR)*Table1[Bonus]) does this what you are asking for?

Hmmm it doesn't seam to work. I update my question to show, that the formula you presented still returns 0. Thanks

@MojoDK please refer my updated screenshot it works on my end

@MojoDK can you test one please: =SUM(--(BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},Table1[Name])),OR))*(Table1[Bonus])) if still not working let me know, i shall add my worksheet

nope stil returns 0 ...strange

@MojoDK do you have the excel? can you post it using one drive link?

... here you go: https://file.io/tuE9VYGX3P8x

@MojoDK download from here: Link

thanks, but it fails here with the error #NAME? ... maybe the formula is not working in a danish version of Excel? Thanks again.

@MojoDK ah ok, let me know one thing are using MS365? if so then the formula needs to be converted to DANISH Version

@MojoDK can you try this:- =SUM(BYROW(ER.TAL(FIND({"Ann";"Peter"};Table5[Name]));OR)*Table5[Bonus]) and let me know

@MojoDK another alternative: =SUM((MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Ann","Peter"},Table1[Name]))),{1;1})>0)*Table1[Bonus])
